# Mean and Variance of total number of fishes.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, means

> The number of fishes caught by a skilled fisherman each day has a
>   Poisson distribution with mean $2.5$. After $50$ days, what is the
>   mean and variance for the total number of fishes the fisherman would
>   have caught ?
>   I know that the $$p(x=k)=\dfrac{e^{-2.5}2.5^{k}}{k!}$$ Now I can't really figure out what next to do. Will the total number of fishes be $50(2.5)$ ?

Would it be right to say that $$E(X)=\sum_{x=0}^{20}x\dfrac{e^{-2.5}2.5^{x}}{x!}$$ and $$V(X)=\left(\sum_{x=0}^{50}x^{2}\dfrac{e^{-2.5}2.5^{x}}{x!}\right)-(E(X))^{2}$$

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $X_i$ be the number of fish caught on day $i$ (for $i=1$ to $50$). Then $S:= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{50}X_i$ is the number of fish caught over the $50$ days. Can you find the expectation and variance of $S$ using the expected value and variance of the $X_i $, along with your knowledge of how to find mean and variance of a sum of random variables? (You may assume for simplicity that the $X_i$ are independent, this was probably implicitly assumed by the question.)